# Не обрабатывается исключение out_of_range

Tags: c++

В книге Principle & practice using c++ приводится пример обработки исключения объекта типа vector в случае попытки обратится за его пределы:

```
int main()
try {
vector<int> v;  // a vector of ints
for (int x; cin>>x; )
v.push_back(x);    // set values
for (int i = 0; i<=v.size(); ++i)    // print values, error is here.
cout << "v[" << i <<"] == " << v[i] << '\n';
} catch (out_of_range) {
cerr << "Oops! Range error\n";
return 1;
// catch all other exceptions
cerr << "Exception: something went wrong\n";
return 2;
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, программа должны выдадть ошибку при попытке выполнить обращение к i-ому элементу вектора, но этого не происходит.
Вот цитата из книги, чтобы было понятно, о чём идет речь:

> So what actually happens when we make such a range error? The subscript operation of vector knows the size of the
>   vector, so it can check (and the vector we are using does; see §4.6 and §19.4). If that check fails, the subscript operation
>   throws an exception of type out_of_range. So, if the off-by-one code above had been part of a program that caught
>   exceptions, we would at least have gotten a decent error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, что автор книги определяет свой класс вектора, у которого оператор индексирования выбрасывает исключение `std::out_of_range`.

Вы же в программе используете стандартный класс `std::vector`, у которого оператор индексирования не выбрасывает исключения.

Вы в своей программе должны использовать тот класс вектора, который автор книги разрабатывает на протяжении своего повествования.

Если же вы просто хотите посмотреть, как работает исключение, и вам не важно, какой класс вектора использовать, стандартный или разрабатываемый автором книги, то вы можете достичь желаемого результата, заменив в предложении

```
cout << "v[" << i <<"] == " << v[i] << '\n';
```

оператор индексирования на вызов функции `at`

```
cout << "v[" << i <<"] == " << v.at( i ) << '\n';
                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

Эта функция в отличии от оператора индексирования проверяет выход за границу вектора и выбрасывает требуемое исключение

Оператор индексирования в векторе ведет себя аналогично оператору  индексирования для обычных массивов, то есть он не проверяет выход за границу массива или вектора.

Comment: Вроде бы нет, используется стандарный библиотечный vector, объявленный в заголовочном файле std_lib_facilities.h - http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h (его якобы для удобства надо подключить и не париться по поводу объявлений)

Comment: @jumpjet67 Я думаю, что вы заблуждаетесь. В любом случае вы можете получить желаемый результат, как это указано в моем ответе.

Comment: @jumpjet67: Строки 97-98: `// disgusting macro hack to get a range checked vector: #define vector Vector`.

Comment: @jumpjet67: Причём этот хак плох ещё потому, что `std::vector` не имеет виртуального деструктора, а значит, наследоваться от него не комильфо. И этот код пишет сам автор языка, эх.

Comment: @VladD  "И этот код пишет сам автор языка" - может новичкам больше и не надо? Я дилетант пока что, но и сам автор упоминает, что файл лишь помогает на первых порах не вдаваться в тонкости языка и изучать идеи и методы, а не их реализации.

Comment: @jumpjet67: Если хотите узнать, почему именно описываемый трюк плох, можно задать отдельный вопрос :) Новичков от подобных трюков надо отучать как можно скорее.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `[]` [не проверяет границы](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at), так что доступ по неправильному индексу — просто UB.
Для проверки диапазона пользуйтесь [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

В книге, судя по всему, ошибка. (Или ошибка перевода.)

Comment: Читаю в оригинале, так что думаю, что ошибка исключена. По умолчанию в программе используется заголовочный файл http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h, может быть проблема в нём?

Comment: @jumpjet67: Значит, информация в книге ошибочна (или устарела). Да, я знаю, кто автор. Но если факты противоречат реальности... (ц)

Comment: издание 2014 года, но дело даже не в этом на самом деле. Просто автор переопределил оператор [ ] в заголовочном файле std_lib_facilities.h, сделав так, чтобы он выбрасывал исключение (По крайней мере такой вывод сделал я, пробежавший по нему глазами), но я этот файл не использую т.к. компилятор выдает ошибку.
А vector.at( ) можно использовать как равноценнуя замену [ ]?

Comment: @jumpjet67: Нет, автор сделал гораздо хуже. Он унаследовался от vector'а, перекрыл невиртуальный `operator []`, и `#define`'ом «подменил» имя `vector` на имя своей реализации. В нормальных командах за такое бьют, и больно. Никогда так не делайте. Выпишите самому себе маленький бонус, когда разберётесь, почему именно так никогда нельзя делать.

Comment: автор допустил фатальную ошибку, но в то же время сам файл и возможности, предоставляемые им используются лишь при рассмотрении первых пяти глав книги. Если ни о каком наследовании пока речи не идет, может можно допустить использование столь грязного хака? С другой стороны, можно было бы сразу показать читателям vector.at( ), ведь, на сколько я понял, им можно безболезнено (и даже с пользой для  себя) заменить vector[ ]. Чтож, допускаю, что страуструп застрял во времени лет 10 назад...

Comment: @jumpjet67: (1) Окей, для начала вполне можно пользоваться `v.at(i)` вместо `v[i]`, вы получите исключение при выходе за границы диапазона индексов. (2) Да, можно этим пользоваться в учебных целях. Если не создавать своих классов и не писать ничего сложного, особого вреда по идее не будет.

Comment: @jumpjet67: Думаю, Страуструп понимает развитие языка (от пишет адекватные тексты), но язык не слишком приспособлен к отладочным фичам (например, в Турбо Паскале контроль границ включался птичкой в настройках проекта), так что он пытается в целях обучения сделать как бы лучше. Хороший разработчик — не значит хороший педагог.